# JUnits ParametrizedTest vs TestTemplate

Tags: java, junit

I recently came across JUnit's feature of `@TestTemplate`, which provides the ability to use generalized test template description, inject it with different test parameters and thus parametrize test runs with context providers.

My question is - how is this `@TestTemplate` mechanism different from the one, achieved through `@ParametrizedTest` + `@SourceValue`? What could be considered as use-cases to prefer `TestTemplate` over `ParametrizedTest`?

Comment: A comparison is presented [here](https://www.baeldung.com/junit5-test-templates), with examples. In short: _"test templates are a powerful generalization of JUnit 5's parameterized and repeated tests."_ Specifically: _"Let's assume that we would now like to run our test method multiple times — not just with different parameters, but also under a different invocation context each time."_ Test templates allow you to do this.

Comment: @andrewjames this is exactly the tutorial I've followed before raising this question, and it was still too generic and abstract to me. Specifically, in this example we're building quite an amount of overhead classes (TestTemplateInvocationContext, TTICProvider, GenericTypedParameterResolver) just to achieve what could have been done with calling SUT class constructor with different parameters, and by providing these parameters through `@ParametrizedTest` method signature as well.